# Clear input fields onfocus

Tags: input, text, onblur, onfocus

I'm having problems creating a couple functions to clear an input field onfocus and reset it back to the default text onblur if it's empty. It works fine until you change some of the text and then backspace it out.

My functions are:

```
function enterField (id, defaultText) {
   if (document.getElementById(id).value == defaultText) {
      document.getElementById(id).setAttribute("value", "");
      document.getElementById(id).style.color = "#000000";
   }
}

function leaveField (id, defaultText) {
   if (document.getElementById(id).value == "" || document.getElementById(id).value == defaultText) {
      document.getElementById(id).setAttribute("value", defaultText);
      document.getElementById(id).style.color = "#dddddd";
  }
}
```

And my html is:

```
<table style="width: 464px; margin-right: -7px; margin-left: -7px; table-layout: fixed;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="8">
    <tr>
        <td class="input"><input id="name" type="text" class="name" size="32" value="Name" onfocus="enterField('name', 'Name');" onblur="leaveField('name', 'Name');"></td>
        <td class="input"><input id="email" type="text" class="name" size="32" value="Email" onfocus="enterField('email', 'Email');" onblur="leaveField('email', 'Email');"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="input" colspan="2"><textarea id="message" class="message" rows="8" onfocus="enterField('message', 'Message');" onblur="leaveField('message', 'Message');">Message</textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: right;" colspan="2"><input id="submit" type="submit" class="button" value="Send"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You can see how it operates at [www.ag-designs.ca/index_new.php](http://www.ag-designs.ca/index_new.php). Click "Let's Talk" at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
document.getElementById(id).setAttribute("value", defaultText);
```

to

```
document.getElementById(id).value = defaultText;
```

at both occurrences in your functions.

Comment: you're welcome :) I'm new to SO and feel happy when I see I've answered something!